# Finding object in list by specific criteria

Tags: java, sorting, collections, stream

I have a list, and must find there specific object.
I must sort list by students averageMark value, and create function that
search for student with second highest value. If it duplicates with other student, the younger one is being returned by function.
The other requierment of this task (to be solved properly) it that I can't create any object. Below I leave the code of class that I am working with:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Student implements Comparator<Student>{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
private double averageMark;

public double getAverageMark() {
    return averageMark;
}

   
//function below must find student that I described upper. Currently 
//function is incomplete because I still try to find correct solution 
public static Student findSecondBestStudent(List<Student> students) {


    return students.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder());
}

@Override
public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
    return (int) (o1.getAverageMark() - o2.getAverageMark());
}
}
```

For now I did try to solve this by doing reverse sorting of the stream, then removing first value of stream and compare two next objects of stream and return the correct one.
I am able to solve it using for loop, but this solution mismatches with condition of task(requiers to create object)

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't create any object"? The student list you might be sorting/searching is also list of objects of Student class, Isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is . I mean I can not create additional objects like variables/arrays etc. I have to do every operations on list given in function args.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `Comparable` rather than `Comparator`.

Make your `compareTo` function so it sorts the students in desired order (reversed)

Sort your `stream`, skip 1 entry, return the next one.

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
  private double averageMark;
  
  public Student(String firstName, String lastName, LocalDate dateOfBirth, double averageMark) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    this.averageMark = averageMark;
  }

  public double getAverageMark() {
    return averageMark;
  }

  //function below must find student that I described upper. Currently 
  //function is incomplete because I still try to find correct solution 
  public static Student findSecondBestStudent(List<Student> students) {
    return students.stream().sorted().skip(1).findFirst().orElse(null);
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Student other) {
    if (other == null)
      return 1;
    if (other.averageMark == averageMark) {
      if (other.dateOfBirth == null)
        return -1;
      return other.dateOfBirth.compareTo(dateOfBirth);
    }
    return Double.compare(other.averageMark, averageMark);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Student [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth
        + ", averageMark=" + averageMark + "]";
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>(6);
    students.add(new Student("Peter", "Tibbitts", LocalDate.of(2001, 4, 6), 5));
    students.add(new Student("Leon", "Gaston", LocalDate.of(1951, 6, 17), 12));
    students.add(new Student("Eric", "Carter", LocalDate.of(1945, 12, 24), 9));
    students.add(new Student("Richard", "Heard", LocalDate.of(1984, 5, 9), 4));
    students.add(new Student("Frankie", "Bonner", LocalDate.of(1970, 4, 19), 10));
    students.add(new Student("Donald", "Pascal", LocalDate.of(2000, 3, 26), 10));
    
    final Student result = Student.findSecondBestStudent(students);
    System.out.println(result);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Beware: I just fixed a typo in comparator: I was checking for `dateOfBirth = null` instead of `other.dateOfBirth == null`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't implement `Comparator<Student>` nor `Comparable<Student>` in `Student` class this way, as I wouldn't necessarily expect students to always be compared this way. But I guess it depends on your use case too.

You can do:

```
public static Student findSecondBestStudent(List<Student> students) {
    return students.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble((Student o) -> o.averageMark)
                    .thenComparing(o -> o.dateOfBirth).reversed())
            .skip(1)
            .findFirst()
            .get();
}
```

Input:

```
List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
        new Student("John", "Wall", LocalDate.of(2005, 1,1), 87),
        new Student("Russel", "Westbrook",  LocalDate.of(2001, 1,1), 88),
        new Student("Micheal", "Jordan",  LocalDate.of(2002, 1,1), 80),
        new Student("Kevin", "Durant",  LocalDate.of(2001, 1,1), 87),
        new Student("Carmelo", "Anthony",  LocalDate.of(2004, 1,1), 80)
);
```

Output:

```
Student(firstName=John, lastName=Wall, dateOfBirth=2005-01-01, averageMark=87.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by providing a custom comparator which compares averageMarks first and then dateOfBirth if found equal:

```java
public static Student findSecondBestStudent(List<Student> students) {
    return students.stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> {
        int marksCompareResult = Double.compare(o2.getAverageMark(), o1.getAverageMark());
        return marksCompareResult == 0 ?
                o1.getDateOfBirth().compareTo(o2.getDateOfBirth()) :
                marksCompareResult;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(1);
}
```

I tested it with the following code:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
students.add(new Student("Rupert", "Brik", LocalDate.of(1994, 12, 30), 51.1));
students.add(new Student("Marc", "Felix", LocalDate.of(1995, 6, 30), 59.1));
students.add(new Student("Max", "Peters", LocalDate.of(1997, 8, 21), 69.1));
students.add(new Student("Mike", "Ermentraut", LocalDate.of(1998, 9, 21), 76.1));
students.add(new Student("Bartosz", "Mazack", LocalDate.of(1999, 10, 12), 76.1));


Student secondBest = Student.findSecondBestStudent(students);
System.out.printf("%s %s %f ", secondBest.firstName, secondBest.lastName, secondBest.averageMark);
```

It prints:

```
Bartosz Mazack 76.100000
```